# JQuery checking if classes matches

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, draggable

I'm trying to make kind of quiz game using html, css, jquery, eventually javascript.
At the moment i want to make if statement, to check if dropped element is dropped in the right div (city). I had an idea to make it with classes and check if they're the same. Is it event possible and proper?

My question is - how can I compare classes of two dives?

```js
$(function() {
  $("#answers div").draggable();
  $("#box div").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      $(this)
        .addClass("ui-state-highlight")
        .find("p")
        .html("Dropped!");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>QUIZ</title>
  <link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>QUIZ</h1>
  <div id="answers">
    <div class="barcelona">
      <p> Antoni Gaudi </p>
    </div>
    <div class="paris">
      <p> Champ Elysees </p>
    </div>
    <div class="london">
      <p> Tate Modern </p>
    </div>
    <div class="barcelona">
      <p> Sagrada Familia </p>
    </div>
    <div class="paris">
      <p> Montmartre </p>
    </div>
    <div class="ny">
      <p> Fifth Avenue </p>
    </div>
    <div class="barcelona">
      <p> Paella </p>
    </div>
    <div class="barcelona">
      <p> La Rambla </p>
    </div>
    <div class="london">
      <p> Piccadilly Circus </p>
    </div>
    <div class="paris">
      <p> Mona Lisa </p>
    </div>
    <div class="ny">
      <p> Empire State Building </p>
    </div>
    <div class="ny">
      <p> Broadway </p>
    </div>
    <div class="paris">
      <p> Musée d'Orsay </p>
    </div>
    <div class="ny">
      <p> Wall Street </p>
    </div>
    <div class="london">
      <p> Camden Town </p>
    </div>
    <div class="ny">
      <p> Big Apple </p>
    </div>
    <div class="barcelona">
      <p> La Boqueria </p>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div id="box">
    <div class="paris">
      <p> PARIS </p>
    </div>
    <div class="ny">
      <p> NY </p>
    </div>
    <div class="london">
      <p> LONDON </p>
    </div>
    <div class="barcelona">
      <p> BARCELONA </p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It would be better to use separate `data-city` attributes. An element can have multiple classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ui.draggable` to find the class and check if that includes in the current element:

```js
$( function() {
  $( "#answers div" ).draggable();
  $( "#box div" ).droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
      var dropped = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[0];
      if(ui.draggable.attr('class').split(' ').includes(dropped)){
        $( this )
        .addClass("ui-state-highlight")
        .find("p")
        .html("Dropped!");
      } 
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<h1>QUIZ</h1>


<div id = "answers">
  <div class = "barcelona"><p> Antoni Gaudi </p></div>
  <div class = "paris"><p> Champ Elysees </p></div>
  <div class = "london"><p> Tate Modern </p></div>
  <div class = "barcelona"><p> Sagrada Familia </p></div>
  <div class = "paris"><p> Montmartre </p></div>
  <div class = "ny"><p> Fifth Avenue </p></div>
  <div class = "barcelona"><p> Paella </p></div>
  <div class = "barcelona"><p> La Rambla </p></div>
  <div class = "london"><p> Piccadilly Circus </p></div>
  <div class = "paris"><p> Mona Lisa </p></div>
  <div class = "ny"><p> Empire State Building </p></div>
  <div class = "ny"><p> Broadway </p></div>
  <div class = "paris"><p> Musée d'Orsay </p></div>
  <div class = "ny"><p> Wall Street </p></div>
  <div class = "london"><p> Camden Town </p></div>
  <div class = "ny"><p> Big Apple </p></div>
  <div class = "barcelona"><p> La Boqueria </p></div>
</div>


<div id = "box">
  <div class = "paris"><p> PARIS </p></div>
  <div class = "ny"><p> NY </p></div>
  <div class = "london"><p> LONDON </p></div>
  <div class = "barcelona"><p> BARCELONA </p></div>
</div>
```

Though it would better to use custom attribute as suggested in the comment:

```js
$( function() {
  $( "#answers div" ).draggable();
  $( "#box div" ).droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
      var dropped = $(this).data('city');
      if(ui.draggable.data('city') == dropped){
        $( this )
        .addClass("ui-state-highlight")
        .find("p")
        .html("Dropped!");
      } 
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<h1>QUIZ</h1>


<div id = "answers">
  <div data-city="barcelona"><p> Antoni Gaudi </p></div>
  <div data-city="paris"><p> Champ Elysees </p></div>
  <div data-city="london"><p> Tate Modern </p></div>
  <div data-city="barcelona"><p> Sagrada Familia </p></div>
  <div data-city="paris"><p> Montmartre </p></div>
  <div data-city="ny"><p> Fifth Avenue </p></div>
  <div data-city="barcelona"><p> Paella </p></div>
  <div data-city="barcelona"><p> La Rambla </p></div>
  <div data-city="london"><p> Piccadilly Circus </p></div>
  <div data-city="paris"><p> Mona Lisa </p></div>
  <div data-city="ny"><p> Empire State Building </p></div>
  <div data-city="ny"><p> Broadway </p></div>
  <div data-city="paris"><p> Musée d'Orsay </p></div>
  <div data-city="ny"><p> Wall Street </p></div>
  <div data-city="london"><p> Camden Town </p></div>
  <div data-city="ny"><p> Big Apple </p></div>
  <div data-city="barcelona"><p> La Boqueria </p></div>
</div>


<div id="box">
  <div data-city="paris"><p> PARIS </p></div>
  <div data-city="ny"><p> NY </p></div>
  <div data-city="london"><p> LONDON </p></div>
  <div data-city="barcelona"><p> BARCELONA </p></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Excerpt from the jQuery UI API Documentation for [droppable](https://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/):

> #### drop( event, ui )
>
> - **event**
> - **ui**
>
>   - **draggable**:
>     A jQuery object representing the draggable element.
>   - **helper**:
>     A jQuery object representing the helper that is being dragged.
>   - **position**:
>     Current CSS position of the draggable helper as { top, left } object.
>   - **offset**:
>     Current offset position of the draggable helper as { top, left } object.

You already knew that `this` is the droppable, now you have access to the `draggable` too. What jQuery calls the `helper` is the element following the cursor. By default those are the same thing, but you could have the draggable stay in place until you drop it while a ghostly clone follows your cursor.

While you could give a class to the draggable and then check for it in the drop event with something like this...

```js
const categories = ["paris", "ny", "london", "barcelona"];

$(function() {
  $("#answers div").draggable();
  $("#box div").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      const $this = $(this);
      
      if (categories.some(c => $this.hasClass(c) && ui.draggable.hasClass(c))) {
        $this
          .addClass("ui-state-highlight")
          .find("p")
          .html("Valid :)");
      } else {
        $this
          .addClass("ui-state-highlight")
          .find("p")
          .html("Invalid :(");
      }      
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>QUIZ</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>QUIZ</h1>
  <div id="answers">
    <div class="barcelona">
      <p> Antoni Gaudi </p>
    </div>
    <div class="paris">
      <p> Champ Elysees </p>
    </div>
    <div class="london">
      <p> Tate Modern </p>
    </div>
    <div class="ny">
      <p> Fifth Avenue </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="box">
    <div class="paris">
      <p> PARIS </p>
    </div>
    <div class="ny">
      <p> NY </p>
    </div>
    <div class="london">
      <p> LONDON </p>
    </div>
    <div class="barcelona">
      <p> BARCELONA </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I would suggest thinking long term however. Eventually, I imagine you'll want to store puzzles in JavaScript.

```
[
  { category: "Paris", answers: ["Champ Elysees", "Montmartre"] },
  { category: "NY", answers: ["Big Apple", "Broadway"] }
]
```

Then you could build the HTML for the puzzles automatically and store the `draggable` and `droppable` widgets in each category. Something like this:

```
categories.forEach(c => {
  c.droppable = createDroppable(c.category);
  c.draggables = c.answers.map(answer => createDraggable(answer));
});
```

You could then compare the draggable and droppable by identity without relying on attributes. I'm not super familiar with  jQuery but I believe this can be done with the `is` method.

```
// in the drop event
const category = categories.find(c => $(this).is(c.droppable));
if (category.draggables.some(answer => ui.draggable.is(answer)) {
  // this answer is valid!
}
```